# it call to generated javascript with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

The native javascript:

```
var Person;
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

This code is working fine if I write in google chrome console `var person = new Person;`

my `main.coffee`

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({})
```

the generated `main.js`

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0
(function() {
  var Person;

  Person = Backbone.Model.extend({});

}).call(this);
```

If I write in google chrome console:

```
var person = new Person;
ReferenceError: Person is not defined
```

**How can I create a instance from console with generated javascript instead native javascript?**

Comment: `var person = new Person();` I would think

Comment: `Person` is not visible in the global scope. You might try `window.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoffeeScript defaults to wrapping all code in a function to avoid polluting the global namespace.  You can compile the code with the `-b`/`--bare` flag to avoid this wrapper, or use `window.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({})` to make it global manually, which is the common way of doing what you want in CoffeeScript.